# How to add SSL certificate for validation when I dockerize my application which is talking to SAP HANA Database?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, jdbc, hana

I am able to connect to the HANA database through my server using JDBC.

```
        public void createDataSource() {
            DataSource dataSource =  DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER)
            .URL("jdbc:sap://localhost:30013/?encrypt=true&validateCertificate=true")
            .username("username")
            .password("password")
            .build();
          
            Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();  
      }
```

Now what I have understood from Documentation is that when I set parameters in the URL:

> validateCertificate=true

If set to true, specifies that the server’s certificate is validated.

Can someone please tell me that when I dockerize my application then how should I upload certificates with it? (Currently, SAP HANA Cloud server certificates are signed using DigiCert Global Root CA root certificate.) Also when the certificate expires then what procedure do I have to follow to re-upload it without hindering my application?

Answer (score 1):

The complete procedure to manage HANA server certificates for securing JDBC/ODBC connections is described in the [SAP HANA Security Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.05/en-US/dbd3d887bb571014bf05ca887f897b99.html).

There are several things that go into managing secure connections and certificates, so I won't repeat them here in detail.

The main steps are

- generate the server certificate and have it signed by the cert. authority of your choice.
- install the server certificate to the HANA instance
- make sure that all clients are able to validate the signed certificate. I.e. the clients need to have the certificate of the certificate authority that signed the HANA certificate available in the **trust store** used by the program that connects.
- make sure that all clients have the HANA server certificate in their **key store** used by the program that connects.

When the server certificate expires, you need to replace it with a valid version. Depending on the HANA version and the certificate management (in database or in filesystem), different tools are used for this.
See [Certificate Management in SAP HANA](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.05/en-US/1e6042c4402545f7a0574f7bc91fab25.html)for details.